# Change Domain and DNS settings on Exchange 2016

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange

I've seen a few questions on this topic, but I have some new ones and am looking for more detail or clarification on some of the answers because I'm super green regarding Exchange. I apologize if any of these questions seem dumb or straightforward, so please bear with me.

We have acquired a company which has an on-prem exchange.
On-prem exchange server name: mail.xyz.com
Autodiscovery  :autodiscover.xyz.com

We noticed they removed xyz.com from the Exchange, added an accepted domain, abc.com, and set it up as a default. Currently, all the email addresses are changed to user1.abc.com and the user webmail login name  xyz\user1
They wanted to keep the xyz.com domain. Currently, they have control of XYZ.com name servers and DNS hostings.
Since they don't want to give up xyz.com,
Is there any way to remove the xyz.com and change it to abc.com

Comment: **Is there any way to remove the xyz.com and change it to abc.com** - Remove it and change it from where?

Answer (score 1):

according to  your description, it is possible to change the default domain from xyz.com to abc.com in Exchange, however, it is recommended that you proceed with caution to avoid any disruption to email services.
The general steps are:

1. Add the new domain (abc.com) as an accepted domain in Exchange.
2. Update all mailbox users' email addresses to use the new domain (abc.com).
3. Change the default email address policy to use the new domain (abc.com).
4. Update any external DNS records (e.g. MX, SPF) to reflect the new domain.

For more information please refer to: [Procedures for accepted domains in Exchange Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/accepted-domains/accepted-domain-procedures?view=exchserver-2019)